# Set span attribute at the moment of logging data with log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, open-telemetry

All problems with business logic in code are written to log with `WARN` or `ERROR` level. The issue is to mark the span if something was went wrog during the code execution. Thus the issue could be stated as *set span attribute `logging.level` to related logging level value* so traces could be processed later in a collector to decide whether to store them or not. I started with the simple `Appender`:

```
public final class OtelAttributeAppender extends AbstractAppender {
  public static final AttributeKey<String> ATTRIBUTE_KEY = AttributeKey.stringKey("logging.level");

  public static void install() {
    final var context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final var logger = (Logger) LogManager.getRootLogger();
    final var appender = new OtelAttributeAppender();
    context.getConfiguration().addLoggerAppender(logger, appender);
    appender.start();
  }

  private OtelAttributeAppender() {
    super(
        OtelAttributeAppender.class.getSimpleName(),
        null,
        PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout(),
        true,
        Property.EMPTY_ARRAY
    );
  }

  @Override
  public void append(LogEvent event) {
    final var span = Span.current();
    final var level = event.getLevel();
    if (span.getSpanContext().isValid() && level.isMoreSpecificThan(Level.WARN)) {
      span.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_KEY, level.name());
    }
  }
}
```

The code above is called but the problem is that `setAttribute` method does not actually set the attribute in a related span. Why? Maybe `Span`s are already ended at the moment of `setAttribute` calls? I've found an [issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/issues/774) but cannot find a way to enable Otel SDK logging. I run my app from IDEA with parameter `-Dotel.javaagent.logging=application`. Tried to set envvar OTEL_LOG_LEVEL to `OTEL_LOG_LEVEL=FINE` or `OTEL_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` but with no luck. How to check if a span is ended?

Maybe there are ideas about setting the attribute using another solution?

Comment: The cause of attribute absence is really that `Span` is ended. Everyting is correct with a solution via custom appender. So, the only question is how to enable SDK debug logging?